# How do I move files to different directories based upon filename?

Tags: java

Okay, I have created a program that will rename the files in a directory based upon creation date.  I now need to be able to move these files into different directories based upon the creation date - 20131202-1.jpg will go into a folder called 20131202 and a file named 20131203-2.jpg into a folder called 20131203, 20131130-1.jpg would go into a folder called 20131130 - creating the directories if needed, etc.  Is there a simple way to do that?  This is the code I used for the rename:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FileRenameAndMove extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField filePath;
    private JTextField outputFile;
    private JButton input;
    private JButton output;
    private JButton rename;
    JFileChooser chooser ;
    File input_Folder = null;
    File output_Folder = null;

    public ExtraCredit(){
        filePath = new JTextField();
        outputFile = new JTextField();
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        input = new JButton("select input Folder");
        output = new JButton("select output Folder");
        rename = new JButton("rename File");
        setTitle("File Mover");
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,200);

        filePath.setBounds(10,10,250,30);
        outputFile.setBounds(10,50,250,30);
        input.setBounds(280,10,150,30);
        output.setBounds(280,50,150,30);
        rename.setBounds(280, 90,150,30);

        add(filePath);
        add(outputFile);
        add(input);
        add(output);
        add(rename);

        input.addActionListener(this);
        output.addActionListener(this);
        rename.addActionListener(this);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExtraCredit();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==input){
              int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
              if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  input_Folder=chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  filePath.setText(input_Folder.getAbsolutePath());
              }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==output){
              int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
              if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  output_Folder=chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  outputFile.setText(output_Folder.getAbsolutePath());
              }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==rename){
              if(input_Folder==null||output_Folder==null){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                            "Please select the source and target folder",
                            "File error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              }
              else{
                  if(input_Folder.exists()){
                      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                      File[] fileList = input_Folder.listFiles();

                      for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++){
                          new File(output_Folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+dateFormat.format(fileList[i].lastModified())).mkdir();
                          fileList[i].renameTo(new File(output_Folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+dateFormat.format(fileList[i].lastModified())+"/"+fileList[i].getName()));
                      }
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                "Files renamed successfully!!",
                                "Information",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                  }
                  else
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                "Source folder doesn't exists",
                                "File error",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              }
        }

    }

}
```

If you can provide a sample on how to do the copying, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a wrote a method to do this. It will first take the current directory and gather a list of all the files+folders in it (not recursive). Then, it will loop through the contents and make sure it is a file that has a "-" in it, in which case it will make the folder and move the file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class tmp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isFile()) {
                String name = files[i].getName();
                if(name.indexOf("-") != -1) {
                    System.out.println(name);
                    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("-"));
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + name + "/").mkdirs();
                    files[i].renameTo(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + name + "/" + files[i].getName()));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Forward slash works on windows in all the Java routines.  There is no need to use File.separator at all.

Comment: @AgilePro thanks for that, I wasn't really sure, never having made code for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `mkdirs()` instead of `mkidr()` to create directory, because: `mkdirs()` Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.
2. The `file1.renameTo(file2)` is not reliable to move a file from one directory to another. The documentation says it:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: **The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists.** The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

So use stream copier(Reader and or writer) approach for copying the target file to a destination directory first and then remove the target file using `delete()` function. Or you can use JAVA NIO support for performance:

```
      public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
       if(!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        try( FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
           FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel()
           ) {
             destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am now going to try to rename the folders by the month year such as Oct2013 instead of the 20131011-1.jpg.  Wish me luck. :)