# Moving files to other folder based on the actual file name

Tags: java

Moving files to other folder based on the actual file name

Move a file from folder1 to other folder based on the file name

**Example:**

Inside D drive: Folder called Tango has 3 files:

```
John1.txt
John2.txt
John3.txt
```

Inside D drive: There are 3 folders called:

```
John1
John2
John3
```

I would like to move the files from Tango folder to other folder(such as John1 or John2 or John3) based on match of file name with folder name.

So far I was able to list the contents of folder, but I am not able to figure how to achieve the above.

```
public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f1 = new File("Tango");
        String[] allFiles = f1.list();

        for (String files : allFiles) {
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343746/2134604

Comment: I think it has already solved many times here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the files in the folder, get name, extract the extension, use [`File.mkDir()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) to create the directory and [`File.renameTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) to move them:

```
// Get array with all files of `Tango`
File[] allFiles = f1.listFiles();

for (File file : allFiles) {
    // extract the extension John1.txt > John1
    String filename = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("."));
    // get the the new folder
    File newDir = new File(filename);

    // create the folder if not exists (delete this if you dont want to make new dir)
    if (!newDir.exists()) {
        newDir.mkDir();
    }

    // and rename it to the new folder + name
    file.renameTo(new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName()));

}
```

Comment: And *move* `file` to `newDir`.

Comment: He already has the directories created, although it would not be a bad idea to create them if they do not already exist.

Comment: fixed move and used `listFiles()` to get folder content... thanks!

Comment: @Jordi Castilla There is no method indexOf in file class

Comment: @kittu sorry... it's fixed, it was `String.indexOf` use `file.getName()`, let me know if you face other issue, i wrote the code *on the fly*

Comment: error in this line `file.renameTo(new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath() + fileName.getName()));` There's no getName() method in fileName(which is a string)

Comment: also fixed..... use `file.getName()` in order to mantain the extension, `filename` does not have it!

Comment: When I ran the program, its moving the text files in to D: drive with names as John1John1.txt John2John2.txt and John3John3.txt

Comment: arg!!! `File.pathSeparator`, of courseeee!!! Fixed!!!

Comment: Now its moving into D: drive as John1;John1.txt John2;John2.txt and John3;John3.txt

Comment: weird.... use `File.separator` or `"\\"` instead....

Answer (score 1):

If you're on at least Java 7 (which you should be):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class FileCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> paths = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("Tango"))) {
            for (Path path : paths) {
                String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
                Files.move(path, path.getParent().resolveSibling(fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 4)).resolve(fileName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try combining [`java.io.File.mkdir()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) and [`java.nio.file.Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to move files that their names contain `john1` to folder `john1` you could use below code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String pathname = "Tango";
        File f1 = new File(pathname);
        String[] allFiles = f1.list();
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (String file : allFiles) {
            if (file.contains("john1")) {
                File source = new File(pathname + "\\" + file);
                File dest = new File("D:\\john1\\" + file);
                inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                int length;
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();
                source.delete();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File folder= new File("Tango");
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        for (Files file : files ) {
                 String filename = file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().indexOf("."));
                 File yourDir= new File(filename); 

              if (!yourDir.exists()) {
                      yourDir.mkDir();
                  }

                file.renameTo(new File(yourDir.getAbsolutePath() + file.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

`.renameTo` : used for moving file

you can create your dir if not exsits

```
 if (!yourDir.exists()) {
        yourDir.mkDir();
    }
```

Comment: The directory is variable in number so I cannot say that are only 3 folders, it could vary later. I have match the file name with folder before moving the files

Comment: @kittu Its working even your number of folders vary cause I have create `yourDir` with filename it self with match exact math folder, You can put code `if(!yourDir.exists())` to create same name folder if not exists.

Comment: Try to put your input before any nagative marking